# Font Size happears bigger than the same size number in a DIV on Mobile Safari

Tags: css, mobile-safari, font-size, html-heading

I'm designing a simple HTML webiste.

I was adjusting the headings (before I had all divs) and I noticed that when I replace a section from DIV to H1 (with the same CSS styles), the text contained in it happears much bigger in Mobile Safari (on Chrome desktop it's perfect).

Has anyone had the same problem and solved it someway?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

it was due to the `font-weight` property which was implicitly set to `bold` on the `h1`.

It's sufficient to *explicitly* set it to `normal`.